# PHPEXCEL export excel in kohana shows machine code how can i clear?

Tags: php, phpexcel, kohana

I have tried this code as like

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    $this->response->body( $objWriter->save('php://output'));
    $this->response->send_file(TRUE, '01simple.xls');
    exit;
```

and error getting like as following image
[image]

Comment: This is not machine code, but its wrongly encoded text :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this...

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../vendor/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Title of my excel");
$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$filename = "file_name";
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thank u. i include your code. Result come like as "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Please make a separate file with only this code. Give right path to `require_once` and then test it .... :)

Comment: Thank u @praveen kumar. i already viewed but controller can't have any function how can to controller in phpexcel.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method its working for me. Set your content in one variable and assign. here I have mentioned example

```
            require_once APPPATH.'libraries/reader/PHPExcel.php';
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $reportHtml = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered" style="border:1px solid #f0f0f0;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Mobile</th>
                  <th>Invoice Id</th>
                  <th>Invoice Date</th>
                  <th>Due Date</th>
                  <th>Balance Amount</th>
                  <th>Total Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>';
            // Put the html into a temporary file
            $tmpfile = time().'.html';
            file_put_contents($tmpfile, $reportHtml);
            // Read the contents of the file into PHPExcel Reader class
            $reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
            $content = $reader->load($tmpfile);
            // Pass to writer and output as needed
            header("Cache-Control: private", false);
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test_1'.time().'.xlsx');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
            unlink($tmpfile);
```

Comment: Thank you. In kohana framework only trouble loading. in outter side of frame working good. plz give me kohana frame work code.

Comment: I do know KOHANA Framework. I just google it and I got some example. I do know how its work . U just go through it
https://github.com/katan/kohana-phpexcel